# Saving awk (index search) output in a shell variable (other than return value)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Consider the following scenario:

```
echo 52=abcd_53=1_54=efgh_55=ijkl | awk -v time_tag="52=" -v start_time="54=" -v end_time="55=" '{p=index($0, time_tag)} {q=index($0, start_time)} {r=index($0, end_time)} /53=1/'
```

I would like to get the value of p,q,r in shell variables so that I can use them after the above command is executed. 
I cannot use shell array since my end goal is something like below:

```
for line in $(cat $dir/$file | awk '/53=1')
do
    for word in $(echo $line | tr "_" "\n")
    do
        if [ ${word:0:3} == "52=" ] ; then
            time_tag=$word
        elif [ ${word:0:3} == "54=" ] ; then
            start_time=$word
        elif [ ${word:0:3} == "55=" ] ; then
            end_time=$word
        fi
    done
    echo $time_tag","$start_time","$end_time
done
```

I want to change the above execution to the following one in hopes of faster execution:

```
for line in $(cat $dir/$file | awk -v time_tag="52=" -v start_time="54=" -v end_time="55=" '{p=index($0, time_tag)} {q=index($0, start_time)} {r=index($0, end_time)} /53=1/')
do
    echo ${line:p:7}","echo ${line:q:7}","echo ${line:r:7}
done
```

I reckon that if I just get the indexes in the awk line itself the program can get significantly faster(for millions of lines) since time is a bottleneck.

Comment: Not clear, please post sample input, sample output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: `for line in $(` is basically already a bug.

Answer (score 0):

*other than return value*—nope, but how about getting rid of that useless `cat` and:

```
$ cat file
52=abcd_53=1_54=efgh_55=ijkl
$ for i in file
  do 
    ret=$(awk -v time_tag="52=" -v start_time="54=" -v end_time="55=" '{p=index($0, time_tag)} {q=index($0, start_time)} {r=index($0, end_time)} /53=1/{print p,q,r}' "$i")
    read -r -a array <<< "$ret"
  done
$ echo ${array[0]}
1
$ echo ${array[1]}
14
$ echo ${array[2]}
22
```

The awk part changed just a bit in the end:

```
awk -v time_tag="52=" -v start_time="54=" -v end_time="55=" '{
    p=index($0, time_tag)
} 
{
    q=index($0, start_time)
} 
{
    r=index($0, end_time)
} 
/53=1/ {
    print p,q,r  # added this and the brackets around this
}' $i
```

Now the awk outputs:

```
1 14 22
```

which is the split on space to `array` with `read`.

Without knowing what's in the files and what the expected output looks like, I can't really do more (ie. rewriting it coompletely in awk).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but from your original script, I assume that the following input

```
52=abcd_53=1_54=efgh_55=ijkl
```

should return the following output:

```
52=abcd,54=efgh,55=ijkl
```

If this is your ultimate goal, then you can just do the following awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[_=]";OFS=","}
     { for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$i"="$(i+1)
       if(a[53]==1) print a[52],a[54],a[55]
       delete a
     }' file
```

This, of course, assumes that all your lines look like this.

If you want to process something like this, with a bash script, you can process this output directly with while-loop

```
awk '{...}' file | while IFS=, read -r time_tag start_time end_time; do
   do what you want to do
done
```

If you want to have a fast execution, then do everything with `awk` and pipe its output to your bash-loop: